# Investigating suspected vote manipulation?

Tags: support, status-completed, votes

I came across a question that has:

- 184 views over 6 months
- On a very specific and convoluted topic (I suspect not many people have come across this issue)

Yet it has 9 upvotes and 3 favourites.

What should we do if we suspect vote manipulation?

Question in question:
[Expression-based labels in scripted Atlas fail to update](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243560/expression-based-labels-in-scripted-atlas-fail-to-update/265213#265213)

Comment: did you check the timeline?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep how do you do that?

Comment: to see the timeline change the url from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243560/expression-based-labels-in-scripted-atlas-fail-to-update/265213#265213  to  https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/243560/timeline

Comment: Yeah based on the timeline the voting and favouriting does not look suspicion, manly after being asked and being tweeted.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I think an answer about using the question timeline to review any voting suspicions would be useful if you have time to post one.

Answer (score 1):

To me that level of viewing and voting does not arouse any suspicion of a voting irregularity.

Most likely it was either shared on Twitter/Facebook/etc, appeared in a GIS SE newsletter, or reached the Hot Network Questions.

If you are suspicious you can always flag for a moderator to investigate, but I think the evidence presented would need to be much stronger before I would spend much time processing such a flag.